# React-Native Google direction api not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps, mobile, google-directions-api

I am developing a mobile application, my aim is to show the distance between two people on the map, I use the Google direction api for this, but there is a problem.  The distance line between the two locations is not visible.  I leave my map.js codes and warnings here.

Codes:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';
export default class Map extends Component{
    state={
        region:{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.015,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
          }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        console.log(this.props.data);
        const {yourLongLat}=this.props.data;
        this.setState({
               region:{
                latitude: yourLongLat[0],
                longitude: yourLongLat[1],
                latitudeDelta: 6,
                longitudeDelta: 6,
            }
 
        }
            
        )
    }
 render(){
    const {yourLongLat,herLongLat}=this.props.data;
    const origin = {latitude: yourLongLat[0], longitude: yourLongLat[1]};
    const destination = {latitude:herLongLat[0], longitude: herLongLat[1]};
    const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = 'don't show api keys';
     return(
         <View style={‌{flex:1, backgroundColor:'green'}}>
        <MapView
        style={‌{flex:1}}
        region={this.state.region}>
            <MapViewDirections
             origin={origin}
             destination={destination}
             apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
             strokeWidth={6}
             strokeColor="hotpink"
            />
        </MapView>
    
 
         </View>
     )
 }
}
```

İmages:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/har5t.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E2Pt.png)

Comment: can you show a console.log of herLongLat[0] and herLongLat[1]?

Comment: You are getting a ZERO_RESULTS status code which means the route between origin and destination doesn't exist for some reason. Can you show us which origin and destination you're querying?

Comment: this console logs: {"herLongLat": [undefined, undefined], "herPhoto": "", "myPhoto": "", "yourLongLat": [52.52000659999999, 13.404954]}

Comment: only showing the distance between american cities and los angeles

Comment: Looks like something goes wrong with ```this.props.data```. Maybe you made a mistake with the variable name ```herLongLat```?

Comment: I solved the problem herLongLat values ​​were wrong